# Trigger MS Bot to proactively send msg to registered user

Tags: c#, triggers, botframework, eventtrigger

I have set up a microsoft bot to capture information on the users that add it to the contacts. I was able to start a new conversation when the skype user initiates conversation.

I do so with a trigger in the RootDialog.cs:

```
t = new Timer(new TimerCallback(timerEvent));
t.Change(5000, Timeout.Infinite);
```

this will initiate a new conversation after 5 ms.

Although this works, This is not what I want to achieve.

Besides the Bot API Controller I have another controller running in my program.

This api which does not use the `[BothAuthentication]` tag receives `http post` request from other systems.

These posts contain information that I then need to send to the user in skype.

Although, I am not able to pass information from one ApiController, that has nothing to do with a Bot Connector, to the Bot Controller which can actually send messages to a user.

What kind of a trigger can I use to fire the action in the bot controller to send the msg to the user I preconfigured? Can I have a list of request coming in from other systems and listen for events on the bot controller? if so how? I checked ObservableCollection but always associated with some Interface binding.

Or can I pass information from one controller to another?

Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Conversations.SendToConversationAsync. [Check this.](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/959)

Comment: Can you provide a full example?

Comment: There is full example.There you have all you need. You have to put that code in some of your methods for resuming conversation. 
Please mark this question as an answer.

Comment: You did answered and it was helpful but it didn't do the trick yet. i am getting 500 internal server error when i reach the following call: await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync((Activity)message);

Comment: This call is in my controller that is does not need BothAuthentication.

Comment: Bob! thanks it worked. I was sending a message with no text on it. for that reason i was getting exception. Now it does work! accepting the answer

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)

Comment: hey bob, now instead of just a message i am trying to pass up a prompt dialog with options for the user to choose. but i am always getting: Microsoft.Rest.ValidationException: 'ReplyToId' cannot be null.
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.ReplyToActivityAsync(IConversations operations, Activity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken). although i know i initialized this value. if i remove this i get the message as expected. but i dont want to stick to just text

Comment: Please ask a new question for this. Use code and better explanation there.

Comment: I did Bob. You can find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43572137/proactive-bot-create-promptdialog-choice Please take a look if you can. Appreciate it.