# Proactive Bot create PromptDialog.Choice

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have a controller that receives post requests from another app.

From that I was able to initiate a conversation with a user that added the bot by doing:

```
ChannelAccount userAccount = new ChannelAccount();
ChannelAccount botAccount = new ChannelAccount();
IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
userAccount = new ChannelAccount(id: "a", name: "b");
botAccount = new ChannelAccount(id: "28:...", name: "bot1");
var connector = new ConnectorClient("uriexample");
var conversationId = await connector.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(botAccount, userAccount);
message.From = botAccount;
message.Recipient = userAccount;
message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: conversationId.Id);
message.ReplyToId = userAccount.Id;
message.Text = "text";
message.Locale = "en-Us";
await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message);
```

This allowed me to prompt a message to the user in my ApiController without the user initiating a conversation first with the bot. Next I send this information to another class by calling:

```
 await Conversation.SendAsync(message, () => new Dialogs.NewDialog());
```

NewDialog:

```
[Serializable]
    public class NewDialog : IDialog<object>
    {
        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            ChannelAccount userAccount = new ChannelAccount();
            ChannelAccount botAccount = new ChannelAccount();
            IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
            userAccount = new ChannelAccount(id:"a", name: "b");
            botAccount = new ChannelAccount(id: "28:...", name: "bot1");
            var connector = new ConnectorClient("uriexample");
            var conversationId = await connector.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(botAccount, userAccount);

            PromptOptions<string> options = new PromptOptions<string>("Hello! yes or no?",
                "Not valid",
                "Exceeded",
                true ?
                new List<string>() { AppConstants.YesOption, AppConstants.NoFraudOption, AppConstants.ExitOption, } :
                new List<string>() { AppConstants.YesOption, AppConstants.ExitOption, },
                3);
                PromptDialog.Choice(context, this.OnOptionSelec, options);

         }

         private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
        {
            var message = await result;

            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }

        private async Task OnOptionSelec(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
        {
            try
            {
                string optionSelected = await result;

                switch (optionSelected)
                {
                    case AppConstants.YesOption:
                         context.Call(new YesDialog(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);
                         break;

                    case AppConstants.NoOption:
                         context.Call(new NoDialog(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);
                         break;

                    case AppConstants.ExitOption:
                         context.Call(new ExitDialog(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);
                         break;
                }
            }
            catch (TooManyAttemptsException)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I do this I get the following error message even though in my API Controller I did set the ReplyToId     `message.ReplyToId = userAccount.Id`; to the user I previously proactively contacted via skype.
:

```
Microsoft.Rest.ValidationException: 'ReplyToId' cannot be null.
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.ReplyToActivityAsync(IConversations operations, Activity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: I don't understand why you have included IDialogs when you initializing conversation ?

BTW : When you are creating conversation, you should have something like this : 

 `var userAccount = new ChannelAccount(toId, toName);
                var botAccount = new ChannelAccount(fromId, fromName);`

Comment: Because there is an external application that wants to connect to my bot and the bot will broadcast to several users. and with that request i'll have to prompt the user with options.

Comment: I use IDialogs because after receiving the request from another app i want to deal with the conversation as a normal bot flow.

Comment: When you are sending message, that is normal bot flow :)))

Comment: But when i use the prompt options code i need to have the context of the application which has to contain a properly formatted activity. Which even when i enter the ReplyToId i have of the user will always give me the ValidationException

Comment: Explain better the flow please

Comment: The flow is: Receive http post from external app in new APIController. And present that request in the form of a choice to the skype user.

Comment: To a different user and in fact, to a user that you have saved somewhere right? if the user never interacted with the bot you won't have the id details and thus you won't be able to connect with him

Comment: Yes, to a user that never started the conversation with. But if i can send a message why can't i send him a choice one?

Comment: What message are you sending to the user? You are sending a message to the API Controller; not to the user. I assume you meant you did this in the past. I don't think that sending a PromptChoice will be possible. You will have to send a message, let the user interact and after that send a PromptChoice. In your code, you are just creating the conversation but you are not sending a message to it either